# Fastest way to read new email from gmail

Tags: c#, gmail

What is the fastest way to read is any new gmail message?
I want to refresh it in about 1 second delay. I'm using GMAIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - The question is not explicit. You need to be more specific.

2 - By the way, here is the official dpcimentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

3 - What i recommend if it is a window service, use Task Scheduling or Quartz to perform every x minutes and implement your logic.